# the navbar layout has problem in bigger screen sizes

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I create a navbar. I started to design it with mobile first method. then I start to design for bigger screen sizes. here I faced to a problem with layout. in navbar I have these elements : logo, li tags, shopping cart icon, button. I want to put logo and li to the right side, and put the shopping cart icon and button to the left. I'll show you the screen capture in mobile:
[here is the screen capture in mobile screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaVPk.jpg) in this size, layout has no problem. but, I will show you the screen capture of bigger screen size:[screen capture in bigger size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHWt5.jpg) the problem is that the li tags go to the left side that it shouden't be like that. it should be next to the logo. I think the problem is in the html codes. the order of the html codes are like this : logo, hamburger menu, shopping cart icon, button and then li tags. I think the problem is because of the li tags are the last elemnt. but if I change the order, I'll faced to a problem in mobile screen size. would you plz help me to solve the problem? By the way, I forgot to say I wrote it with css flex.
here is the html codes:

```css
*{
  font-family: myfont;
  direction: rtl;
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
}
.nav-logo{
    width: 70px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.hamburger-menu{
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #e63946;
}
nav{
    padding: 10px;

    background-color: #ffffff;
    background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.25 );
    box-shadow: 0 8px 32px 0 rgba( 31, 38, 135, 0.37 );
    backdrop-filter: blur( 17.5px );
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur( 17.5px );
    border: 1px solid rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.18 );
}
.row{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.right{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    margin-right:30px;
}
.left{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin-left:30px;
}
.column{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.nav-item{
    list-style: none;
}
.nav-item a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #35357a;
    line-height: 40px;
}
.nav-item a:hover{
    color: #e63946;
}
.btn-login{
    background-color: #e63946; 
    color:white; 
    border: none;  
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius:50px;
    font-size: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}


@media screen and (min-width: 646px) {
    nav{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
    }

    .nav{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
        flex-direction: row;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    .navbar{
        list-style: none;
        display: flex;
        justify-content:flex-end;
    }
    .column{

    }
    .hamburger-menu{
        display: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 25px;
        color: #e63946;
    }
    .right{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content:flex-end;
    }
    .left{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        margin-left: 20px;
    }

}
```

```html
<body>
<nav class="nav">
   <section class="row">
       <div class="right">
            <div>
                <img class="nav-logo" src="images/golgasht1.png"/>
            </div>
            <div class="hamburger-menu">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="left">
                <span class="cart-btn">
                    <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                    <span class="cart-items">0</span>
                  </span>
                  <a href = "register&login/login.php"><button class="btn btn-login px-4 ml-5">ورود </button></a>
                </div>

                </section>

                <section class="column">
                <ul class="navbar">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link">فارس گردی</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="gallery.php" class="nav-link">گالری عکس</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="Vtour.php" class="nav-link">تور مجازی</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="weblog.php" class="nav-link">وبلاگ</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </nav>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Put all of your navbar items into one flex container, and use the `order` property and `@media` queries to change their visual order.**

You correctly noticed that your HTML markup was the problem. There are two `section` elements inside your `nav`, and that made it hard to put one `section` (the links) in between the elements of the other `section` (between the shopping cart and the logo).

This layout can be achieved with either CSS Grid, or with Flexbox. I’ll stick to Flexbox because you already started with it.

**Mobile-first layout**

- vertically arrange the list of links
- place the list of links below all the other elements of the navbar (we’ll use `flex-wrap: wrap` to create a multi-line flex container, and `flex-basis: 100%` on the list of links to make sure it *wraps* into a second line)

[Screenshot of the mobile layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yswit.png)

**Large screen layout (defined in a `@media` query)**

- hide the hamburger menu button
- horizontally arrange the list of links
- place the list of links after the logo, and before the other elements in the navbar. We’ll reset the `flex-basis` of this item so it no longer wraps into a second line and use the `order` property to change the visual order

[Screenshot of the large screen layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WI4U7.png)

**The [`order`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) property** lets us keep our HTML markup in the same order, but change the visual order of the individual flex items. So you can have your list of links last in your HTML, but then visually show it somewhere else.

All flex items start with an initial `order` value of `0`. Because they’re all in the same *ordinal group* of `0`, they will be visually laid out in the same order as your HTML. But if you give your list of links an `order` of `-1`, then it will be laid out before all the items with `order: 0`.

Here’s a simplified version of your code with a working solution:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 16px;
  padding: 24px;

  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.shopping-cart-icon {
  margin-inline-start: auto;
}

.login-button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #e63946;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

nav {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

.link-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.link-list li {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px 0;
}

.logo {
  width: 80px;
}

.hamburger-menu-button {
  width: 32px;
}

.shopping-cart-icon {
  width: 40px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 646px) {
  .hamburger-menu-button {
    display: none;
  }

  .logo {
    order: -2;
  }

  nav {
    order: -1;
    flex-basis: initial;
  }

  .link-list {
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 16px;
  }
}
```

```html
<body dir="rtl">
  <header class="navbar">
    <img class="logo" src="https://i.imgur.com/fFezxJ0.png" alt="Logo" />
    <img class="hamburger-menu-button" src="https://i.imgur.com/8bIOZ09.png" alt="Menu" />
    <img class="shopping-cart-icon" src="https://i.imgur.com/3jN32Vl.png" alt="Shopping cart" />
    <a class="login-button" href="login.html">ورود</a>
    <nav>
      <ul class="link-list">
        <li><a href="#">فارس گردی</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">گالری عکس</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">تور مجازی</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">وبلاگ</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: thank you. at first the problem solved completely. but when I set the href for button, I could see the hamburger menu in bigger screen sizes. why is this happening? the display is none !!!!

Comment: @setarezre It’s difficult to tell without seeing your code. You need to make sure that you’re setting `display: none` on the exact element you don’t want to have rendered.